# How to connect to WSDL service using Binding Url in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, soap, wsdl

I have been provided a Web Service which i need to consume in my MVC application .
The user has provided 
**WSDL URL :** 
http://abc.xyz.nirp.com:50000/dir/wsdl?p=ic/310c503c873138a884ddd3ee4a5738e6

**Binding Url:**
http://abc123.ad.xyx.com:50000/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&senderService=BS_HARMONY_D&receiverParty=&receiverService=&interface=ABC_OS&interfaceNamespace=http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Fhcm%2Fabc

I am able to add a service reference using the WSDL URL using SOAP credential but i also need to add these in the web configs and app configs  which i am not able to understand where to put .

Pointers on how to use this Binding Url and put it in Web Config and App Config  which be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your web.config. After adding a service reference visual studio adds the endpoint in your web.config. You probably have a section like that:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultServiceEndpoint">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="ADDRESS_HERE"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultServiceEndpoint"
        contract="ServiceReference1.SOME_CLASS" name="DefaultServiceEndpoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

You can change the address here.

Comment: so the complete Binding URL , i should add in place of 'ADDRESS_HERE'?

Comment: and in place of ServiceReference1.SOME_CLASS , is there anything that should be added?

Comment: When you add the service reference these properties already have value. The only property you should change if necessary is the address.

Comment: i dont have wsHttpBinding Tag but basicHttpBinding.

Comment: Sould i continue with the basicHttpBindnig?

Comment: Yes, this example I posted is based on a Service that requires a different binding. Again: the only property you should change if necessary is the address.

Comment: Although now i need to consume the methods of that service. How do i need to do that?